# QGRID: Is it possible to enable a left-right scrollbar when displayed in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, qgrid

I checked the [qgrid documentation](https://qgrid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is based on the SlickGrid library.  The [SlickGrid grid options](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Options) do not show something.  However it seems odd that a web based library would not allow scrolling left or right if all of the data does not fit within the current view.  As you can see below, my dataframe has 95 columns and only 10 are visible, with no scrollbar top access the other ones.

[image]

thx